# tmux: confusing behavior with redirection and piping

Tags: linux, bash, tmux

Here is what I am trying to do - copy tmux buffer contents to a file.

First attempt:

```
$ tmux show-buffer > myfile
```

This "hangs", as in never completes.

However, I can do something like:

```
$ tmux show-buffer | cat > myfile
```

Then I try something else, use the 'tee' command instead:

```
$ tmux show-buffer | tee myfile

..
..

tee: write error
```

It displays "tee: write error" at the end, with the .. indicating part of the buffer it also prints, but not (as it should) print the whole buffer. The file has the entire contents, however.

I believe this has something to do with how `tmux show-buffer` works and it's relation to the redirection and piping behavior. Would someone know more about this?

Comment: `tmux show-buffer > myfile` works here, so works with `tee`

Comment: @kent: it seems to be a problem with my tmux version which was 1.5

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been an issue with an older tmux version (1.5). With 1.8, it works just fine.

Related [link](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=631984)